# Enquiry about RESTful API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I would like to know what technologies would be best to add a RESTful API to a website set up with HTML and CSS so that the owner of the website **can log in and add entries for news about their business** and why I should use this library/technology. I'd appreciate any sort of help or redirection to learning resources. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are interested in working with JavaScript. You can create an API in nodejs + express with react as the front-end.

Comment: Frankly, a RESTful API is the wrong approach unless your app is already a single-page application (SPA) or you need third-party clients to also have access. If you just want an admin user interface, it's probably unnecesssary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of depends on the website, what it's built on, and how it's deployed; but my go-to answer for something like this is to look into something like express.js first, which can serve up both the front-end and back-end.  There's a ton of examples online on how to do this.  Here's the first I googled: https://medium.com/@maison.moa/setting-up-an-express-backend-server-for-create-react-app-bc7620b20a61

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much, I'll look into this right now. Looks like exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Feel free to +1 & accept ;) if this takes you down the right path

Answer (score -1):

You might want to consider WordPress. If you want the owner to have more customization over the website, here is a link that gives a brief overview: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wordpress-admin/